# "Save" and "Cancel" buttons disappeared from bottom of a form

Tags: button

We created a form a couple years ago and have been using it with no problems. One of the users of this form mentioned to us the other day that the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons are no longer at the bottom of the form. The only way to save the information on the form is to scroll all the way to the top of the form when you're done filling it out and click the "Save" button in the ribbon...which is not very intuitive. Where did the standard "Save" and "Cancel" buttons go and how do I get them back?

Here is a screenshot of a form that is working (and has the buttons):
[image: working]

Here is a screenshot of the form that is NOT working (and the buttons are missing):
[image: not working]

Comment: Please add information about which version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: SharePoint Server 2010

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, the form with missing buttons also appears to have all form fields grayed out (disabled).  Do your forms have multiple views configured in them to be displayed under different conditions?

Comment: That helped me find it.

Comment: ...in General Settings > Form Settings we changed this setting to customize the form in order to add the images of the Standard Name Badge and Name Badge with Department at the top of the form. When I changed this back to use the standard form, the buttons returned. So now the question is how to we add the images at the top of the page without making the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons disappear?

Comment: RESOLVED! I was able to reset the form to include the buttons again, which removed the image from the top of the form. Then I added a web part for the image and now the form is back to normal again. Thank you!